# Safari does not play HTML 5 video (IE 9, Firefox and Chrome all do)

Tags: html, safari, video-streaming

I am aware that I need ogg for Chrome and Firefox and H.264 for IE 9 and I use multiple sources to support all browsers with my video, and I also have the required meta to keep IE 9 happy enough:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>

  <video loop autoplay> 
    <source src="fito.ogg" type="video/ogg">    
    <source src="fito.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="fito.m4v" type="video/x-m4v">
  </video>
```

The first is the newest ogg and the second is legacy H.264 (IE 9 seems not playing the newer M4V). The last is m4v that no browser seems playing. Now all three major browsers do play the video just Safari does not and I have a requirement to support this one as well. Does anybody know how Safari is different from IE 9 in HTML 5 video support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked fine for me on Safari 5.1 on Windows 7.

Do you have QuickTime installed? Safari needs QuickTime to play HTML5 video.

Comment: Works for me on OSX 10.8, Safari 6.

Comment: I have tested myself, really seems only broken on some machines probably with missing QuickTime. Agree.

Comment: So that's what it was then? How very annoying :-/